# Actual memory used by web server. Memory not released to OS

Tags: go, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I push a bunch of requests through the web server, and according to Htop / activity monitor on my mac, Virt is 530G, Res is 247Mb.

The memory doesn't seem to be being released to the OS. I tried adding the following for force memory to be returned to OS as a test to no avail:

```
func freeMem() {
    tick := time.Tick(time.Second * 10)

    for range tick {
        debug.FreeOSMemory()
    }
}
```

and at the top of main, calling `go freeMem()`, but this seems to have no effect.

So I tried checking garbage collector is working properly and visualising with dave cheney's gcvis https://github.com/davecheney/gcvis:

Looks like gcvis shows things are working fine and dandy, but htop & activity monitor seem to be v high memory usage.

Do I have anything to worry about? One thing I did notice in gcvis, is that whilst `gc.heapinuse` goes down to acceptable levels, `scvg.released` and `scvg.sys` seem to remain high.

[image: gcvis output]

[image: htop & activity monitor]

Comment: According to [this issue report](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14521), this behavior is normal. If there is enough pressure on memory in the system from other processes, the OS should start to reclaim the memory from the Go process that Go has marked as unused.